# pandas isin using multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to assign `True/False` value to each row in my pandas dataframe if the row contains certain values for columns that I specified. For example, suppose I had the following dataframe:

```py
d = {
    "col1": ["alpha", "beta", "alpha", "gamma", "alpha"],
    "col2": [1, 2, 2, 3, 1],
    "col3": ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    col1  col2 col3
0  alpha     1    a
1   beta     2    a
2  alpha     2    b
3  gamma     3    c
4  alpha     1    d
```

I know that if I wanted to create a row mask using values for a single column I can use pandas's `isin`. For example, if I want all rows that contain `alpha` in `col1`, I can do the following: `df['col1'].isin(["alpha"])`.

```py
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
```

How do I get similar behaviour but with multiple columns? What if I wanted to set all rows that have `alpha` in `col1` AND `1` in `col2` to `True` and everything else `False`?

I would like to have a function that takes in a dataframe and a dictionary as an input. The dictionary would have keys corresponding to column names and values as lists of values that I want. The function returns a pandas Series of booleans where each row is `True` if the corresponding row in the dataframe contains values in the dictionary and `False` otherwise. For example:

```py
def multi_column_isin(df, d):
    <implementation>
    s = pandas Series where each row is True if it has values in d else False
    return s

s = multi_column_isin(df, {"col1": ["gamma", "alpha"], "col2": [1, 3]})
s

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the dictionary you would like to pass to the function?

Comment: The dictionary is provided in the question: `{"col1": ["gamma", "alpha"], "col2": [1, 3]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can script a function to do this:

```py
def multi_column_isin(df, d):
    # get rid of the index to avoid index alignment
    booleans = [df[col].isin(arr).array for col, arr in d.items()]
    return np.logical_and.reduce(booleans)

multi_column_isin(df, {"col1": ["gamma", "alpha"], "col2": [1, 3]})
array([ True, False, False,  True,  True])


# alternative route with pipe
 df.pipe(multi_column_isin, {"col1": ["gamma", "alpha"], "col2": [1, 3]})
array([ True, False, False,  True,  True])
```

A simpler way would be to pass a dictionary to `isin` - sometimes though, this can result in incorrect/unwanted output, depending on index alignment:

```py
(df
.drop(columns='col3')
.isin({"col1": ["gamma", "alpha"], "col2": [1, 3]})
.all(1)
)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me an example where passing a dictionary to isin would result in incorrect output?

Comment: The one that comes to mind is if the values in the dictionary are series and not array/list. Index alignment will occur first and if the indices differ, you might get unlikely errors. I might be wrong, but it is something I felt I should mention.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
(df.col1 == 'alpha') & (df.col2 == 1)
```

Should get you there.